# Using WiringPi with Jasper (voice recognition)

Tags: gpio, python, electronics, wiringpi, pi-b+

I am using [Jasper](http://jasperproject.github.io/).

The *voice control* part works, however the function I call when a certain word is said, does not.

I'm trying to control a robot, sending high signals to certain pins on an L293D chip. I've made a simple function to easily set multiple pins high:

```
import wiringpi2 as wiringPi
wiringPi.wiringPiSetupSys()

def goHigh(*arg): #for multiple pins
    for pin in arg: 
        wiringPi.digitalWrite(pin, 1)
```

But when I call that function with a certain word, I get the error `NameError: global name 'wiringPi' is not defined`:

```
ERROR:client.brain:Failed to execute module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/jasper/boot/../client/brain.py", line 73, in query
    module.handle(text, self.mic, self.profile)
  File "/home/pi/jasper/client/modules/robot.py", line 64, in handle
    goForward(mic, message)
  File "/home/pi/jasper/client/modules/robot.py", line 29, in goForward
    goHigh(A1,B2)
  File "/home/pi/jasper/client/modules/robot.py", line 12, in goHigh
    wiringPi.digitalWrite(pin, 1)
NameError: global name 'wiringPi' is not defined
```

It seems that Jasper cannot see WiringPi as being installed. What I've tried:

- Building WiringPi in the Jasper directory
- Normally building it in my `home`

But this still doesn't work; I presume because WiringPi builds in its own folder, and Jasper looks for a single file.

How can I fix this? So I can use WiringPi with Jasper?

Comment: I don't think it is installed properly.

Comment: How am I supposed to install it? I cloned it from github and built it currently...It's worth saying that running this myself, in python, does work, it's just jasper

Comment: Here : follow this : http://raspi.tv/how-to-install-wiringpi2-for-python-on-the-raspberry-pi

Comment: OK, I installed it following http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/; I'll try using pip tonight and see if that works, however id does already work if I type in some commands manually! It's just with Jasper that causes the problem :(

Comment: Please note that, wiring pi is originally written in C while what you're trying to use is its python wrapper. The link that you provided doesn't install its python wrapper by default as far as I know.

Comment: I think it does because I can use it by typing the commands to make the pins high/low manually in the python interpreter, it just doesn't work with Jasper! :( Do you know of any other ways to control the GPIO pins via Jasper -- I can't use the GPIO library because if I run jasper with sudo it errors out!

Comment: Not sure, what could be the issue with `sudo` and `jasper` but how about importing system module and use `os.system("gpio write 0 0")` to read or write values. Not the best way, can work temporarily.

Comment: hmmm, not a bad idea; hacky -- but it would work... :/ You can put that as an answer if you want! :) BTW should I post another question about the error I get with Jasper sudo'ed?

Comment: I've heard a lot about jasper project but haven't really tried using it. Feel free to ask a question, if not me, there're chances that someone who has already worked on it would answer the question. Also, added the work around as the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, since the OP's having difficulty using `jasper` modules with `sudo`, I suggest to use the `os` module in python and call the system `gpio` utility by `os.system`.

For example,

```
import os
# import other modules

#do other works.

os.system("gpio write 0 0")
```

Hope it helps.